# Mosquito Trap high Voltage

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, high-voltage

**Here is the circuit, A and B are connected to the 2 plates.**

[image]

**Here is how it is supposed to work.**
[image]

Q1, how safe is this trap to a human?

Q2, Basically how does it work?

Q3, Is there a current limiting circuit or is this a dead trap for human too?

Comment: q1 and q3 are the same...

Comment: Very similar ones are covered in [these](https://youtu.be/caIRL1ci22Y) [videos](https://youtu.be/LtXmsxRdiUw). They can kill you even when not connected to the grid, because there are no bleeder resistors for the HV caps.

Comment: @TurboJ the diodes at least block the HV from the pins. Even if you touch the plates with the caps charged, I don't think 25mJ is going to kill anyone unless it startles you and you fall into a wood chipper or something.

Comment: Even if someone touches the plates with its bare fingers, the only thing that happens is a frightening shock, but there will not be any death or injury, because the current value is below the limit for doing harm, and also, because the current flows through a very narrow part of the body (only the a 1/8 inches to connect an electrical plate to another).  If it where deadly Amazon not would be selling something like [this racket](https://www.amazon.com/Zap-Bug-Zapper-Rechargeable-Super-Bright/dp/B01JBU4WE4/ref=sr_1_7?s=lawn-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1508678799&sr=1-7&keywords=bug+zapper)

Comment: The [racket](https://www.amazon.com/Zap-Bug-Zapper-Rechargeable-Super-Bright/dp/B01JBU4WE4/ref=sr_1_7?s=lawn-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1508678799&sr=1-7&keywords=bug+zapper) is effective, because you chase the bugs with it. But I don't think that this wall-plug trap would really atract mosquitoes, even if using UV light: in my experience, mosquitoes likes dark spots, and would not fly to an UV source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plates could be deadly or cause injury if you touch them, depending on what else you are touching (such as a ground) and whether you touch one or both plates.

Usually safety agencies require that a proxy for a human (child human) finger  should not be able to touch anything harmful. Here is an articulated test "finger" for IEC testing from [this](http://www.iectestingequipment.com/sale-2226127-ul-standard-articulated-test-finger-probe-ul474-fig-5-1-ul507.html) website. Rather expensive and specialized device, but you get the idea.

[image]

It looks from the photo like the gaps in the housing may be too large and the electrically "hot" parts too close to the face to be safe. There should also be a fuse -- maybe you didn't show it since you didn't show the switch.

There's not necessarily much inherently unsafe about this circuit but it would have to be protected, and the housing needs to be  made from appropriately fire retardant plastic. All of which should be doubted without evidence to the contrary.

Aside from safety, I have my doubts that the relatively low 600V voltage will actually kill bugs- effective bug  killers usually have a step-up into the kV. Not all bugs are that 'juicy'.  It might just tickle them a bit. The visible LED should either be inverse parallel LEDs or have a parallel shunt diode.

---

As to how it works  (to the extent it actually does work), the two diodes and 220nF capacitors form a voltage doubler, which will produce around 660V peak across the plates with no load. It is effectively short-circuit proof (barring failures of the capacitors or diodes) because a direct short between the plates will only conduct current through the two 220nF capacitors in parallel (440nF), which is about about 33mA assuming 240V/50Hz. However if one of the parts fails there should be a fuse to limit the current and prevent a fire. The LED (see my note above) appears to use a capacitive dropping circuit but the values you have found may not be correct. There is a bleeder resistor across the cap to prevent the pins from giving the user a tingle when they are pulled out from the wall.

Comment: It is not unsafe, or else Amazon would not be selling this [racket](https://www.amazon.com/Zap-Bug-Zapper-Rechargeable-Super-Bright/dp/B01JBU4WE4/ref=sr_1_7?s=lawn-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1508678799&sr=1-7&keywords=bug+zapper). I own two of then and IS efective. My kids (ages 9, 11) use the racket and sometimes one of us get a shock, but definitely is not harmful. It works even if the bug is not "juicy": it seems to me that it damages the bugs' nervous system, too; this shock is effective, due to the very low bug's weight and its minimal size. It doesn't needs "fry" or "cook" the bug.

Comment: The racket you refer to may be running with different voltages / charges....

Comment: @mguima That device operates on a completely different principle- battery operated which is inherently safer. Also they actually do claim several thousands of volts, which should mean it will actually work. Others claim up to 4.5kV. They could generate some kV with a Cockroft-Walton multiplier, but it would cost them an extra few 元 per unit.

Comment: @mguima Even with the unit switched off a mains power unit unless there is a DPDT switch can easily cause a fatal shock because the mains voltage can pass through the body of the victim to ground. Also, I would not be too confident that Amazon sales guarantee safety. I have seen some stuff sold there that was.. questionable. Personally when purchasing in bulk I verify any claims of approvals with the standards agencies- often enough even if approvals or listings are claimed they turn out to be ephemeral. Caveat emptor.

Comment: @ Spehro, I agree with you about about the mains power unit; and, thinking about it again, I would not have a wallplug mosquito trap. But about the battery racket, I know that the fact that the racket is sold by Amazon is not a full guarantee. But, I live outside US and I tought that my country's standards were not strong enough and that was the reason I could by one. But, when I saw the racket in Amazon, it seemed to me that it is not forbidden by the highest (I think so) US governamental safety standards.

Comment: @mguima The US does not have federal electrical safety regulations governing sale of products not used in the workplace. You are free to sell shoddy dangerous goods, but most retailers will demand approvals and/or insurance. Local regulations may require, say, UL listing for items to be plugged into the electrical grid.  Larger Amazon.com sellers must carry $1m in product liability insurance, so your heirs may be able to cash in if anything goes badly wrong.